# how to delete an image on a sheet

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, excel, vsto

hi let's say i have images on my excel worksheet, how is it possible to delete/remove them from the sheet using c#,

following code gives me exception

```
        Excel.Worksheet ws = Globals.ThisAddIn.GetActiveWorksheet();
        foreach (Excel.Shape sh in ws.Shapes)
        {
            sh.Delete();
        }
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

never mind, i forgot that my sheet was protected,

```
    Excel.Worksheet ws = Globals.ThisAddIn.GetActiveWorksheet();
    ws.Unprotect("PASSWORD");
    foreach (Excel.Shape sh in ws.Shapes)
    {
        sh.Delete();
    }
```

it works fine!